# How to scale div smoothly in css using keyframes

Tags: html, css

I want to smoothly scale the div from ratio `0.06 to 1` using css on mouseover.but i m not able to get that effect.

Here is what i have tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: transform 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s, height 4s;
}

div:hover {
    transform:scaleX(0.06);
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes example {
    25%  {transform:scaleX(0.200);}
    50%  {transform:scaleX(0.500);}
    75%  {transform:scaleX(0.700);}
    100% {transform:scaleX(1);}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div>jhk</div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

try this. You don't need transition when using key frames

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: red;
     -webkit-transform:scaleX(0.06);
     transform:scaleX(0.06);
}

div:hover {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {-webkit-transform:scaleX(0.06);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:scaleX(1);}
}
@keyframes example {
    0%   {transform:scaleX(0.06);}
    100% {transform:scaleX(1);}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div>jhk</div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really specify how you want to transition everything so here is a basic example:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition: all ease-in 2s;
    transform:scale(0.06);
}

div:hover {
    transform:scale(1);
}
```

You don't need keyframes for smooth animations. Something simple like that can be accomplished with simple CSS `transform`s.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mh90y3xv/

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `@keyframes` just use `transition`.

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/6voh58hx/)**.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="animate">
        jhk
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** You must add a `div` with a class `animate` to maintain the `transition`.

**CSS**

```
div,
.animate {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}    

.animate {
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

div:hover > .animate {
    -webkit-transform:scaleX(0.06);
    -moz-transform:scaleX(0.06);
    -o-transform:scaleX(0.06);
    transform:scaleX(0.06);
}
```

**In this case,** using `transition` is a lot smoother than `animation` and `@keyframes`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want something like this.

**CSS**

```
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
-webkit-transition: all .06s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .06s ease-in-out;
transition: all .06s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
-ms-transform: scale(0.6);
-o-transform: scale(0.6);
 transform: scale(0.6);
}

@keyframes example {
25%  {transform:scaleX(0.200);}
50%  {transform:scaleX(0.500);}
75%  {transform:scaleX(0.700);}
100% {transform:scaleX(1);}
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8qMm/42/)